# How to Change Image Style When Clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I'm setting up a quiz for a new website that saves user preferences based on the options they select. The idea is the 'quiz' displays a number of images, which can be selected by clicking on them. Once selected, they are 'greyed out' which I plan to do by changing the opacity of the image.

Unfortunately my knowledge of web coding is very limited and I can't figure out how to change the style of an image when it's clicked.

My starting point is essentially this:

```
<a href="https://manilva.club/1103-2/?frame-nonce=64ca5428e3">
    <img src="https://manilva.club/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/Akielo-Metal-2.jpg" />
</a>
```

If my understanding is correct, I need to add some java that will alter the image when it's clicked.

Comment: simples way is create `css` class, and on click swap it (also you can change src for it)

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay first of all, you need to use Javacsript in order to add a class to your img element, I created a snippet in which when you click the anchor containing the image, the image changes its opacity, if you click it again it goes back to normal.
Note the function `addClassToImage`.

I also added a transition effect for the opacity of the image, notice the CSS section below.

Here's the snippet:

```js
function addClassToImage(element) {
 var innerImage = element.querySelector('img');
  if(innerImage) {
   if(innerImage.classList.contains('clicked')) {
    innerImage.classList.remove('clicked');
    }
    else {
    innerImage.classList.add('clicked');
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.img-class {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-out;
}

.clicked {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="addClassToImage(this)">
    <img class="img-class" src="https://manilva.club/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/Akielo-Metal-2.jpg" />
</a>

<a href="javascript:;" onclick="addClassToImage(this)">
    <img class="img-class" src="https://manilva.club/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/Akielo-Metal-2.jpg" />
</a>

<a href="javascript:;" onclick="addClassToImage(this)">
    <img class="img-class" src="https://manilva.club/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/Akielo-Metal-2.jpg" />
</a>
```

Comment: I have a quick follow-up question, if you don't mind. Is it possible to apply the above to multiple images or is the easiest way to do this by re-using the html part of the answer multiple times?

Comment: I updated my answer to include multiple images, so to answer your question, yes you need to add those multiple images to the HTML, notice the `onclick` event, I'm passing `this` as a parameter, which refers to the element being clicked, so every time the `addClassToImage` function is called, it gets the clicked element and finds the inner image of that element using `querySelector`, hope this explains it for you.